# Would like jQuery Mobile panel Open by default

Tags: jquery, mobile, panel, default

Is there a way of altering the default state of a JQuery Mobile panel to be open when the page loads?

Currently using jQuery Mobile 1.4.1 and can't find anything in the documentation and searched every where I can think online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $( "#mypanel" ).panel( "open");
});
```

With "index" and "mypanel" being respectively the ids of your page and your panel.

Comment: That works when straight loading the page (Yay!) Unfortunately when opening the page from another page it appears to have the panel open then closes it once the page finishes loading. Tried putting the script at the bottom of the page but no success.